# How do I remove this menu bar?

Tags: menus

I just use the pages for navigation.

I don't need the menu bar that has the single item - uncategorized.

Here is the link to the theme being used.

http://themeforest.net/item/deadline-premium-wordpress-news-magazine-theme/faq/117203

Is this a theme issue or part of the word press core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be better directed to the theme developer, as there may be an even easier way of doing this, but there are 3 basic methods to remove a menu:

1. #### Unregister the menu

   This might cause issues with the `wp_nav_menu()` call, but you can use [`unregister_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_nav_menu) to remove the menu. You will need to know what it is called.
2. #### Remove the call to the menu

   If you open up the header.php file you should see a call to `wp_nav_menu()` in the `<div>` with id `primary-nav`. Remove this and the menu will go away
3. #### Remove the menu registration

   This will probably have to be done in tandem with the first if you do decide to do it, you'll be looking (hopefully in `functions.php`) for a call to `register_nav_menu()` or `register_nav_menus()`, you will need to remove the element that creates the menu.
4. #### Hide the menu with CSS

   This is probably the worst option, but it is a viable option. You should set `display: none` on `#primary-nav` if you want to use this method. You can either use a plugin to do this or modify `style.css` directly.

Again, your best option is probably to contact the theme developer for this, but if that's no use or you just want to learn, these are the ways (in order of best-to-worst practice, IMO) to do it.